# Looking for automotive data (camera images for feature extraction, tracking, fusion etc.)

Tags: images, machine-learning

I recently graduated from college and realize that I need to turn my theoretical knowledge into skills. I am very much interested in the automotive industry. There, experts for Advanced Driving Assistance Systems (ADAS) functions like Automated Emergency Braking (AEB), Lane Departure Warning (LDW), Parking assistants and upcoming functions for autonomous driving are needed. I am looking for projects which provide data for exactly this or similiar functions. I think it will be hard if not impossible to find data that describes a whole function from one of the above. But there are similiar skills needed in many other topics.

I want to cover the following topics

- image processing (detect cars, lanes, traffic signs, etc.)
- kalman filtering/ particle filters etc. (represents the state of an image feature.)
- object tracking (track one feature e.g. a blue car over a series of pictures/ video)
- object fusion (let's say there is redundant data of one and the same feature, because the feature is tracked with radar and camera. Then I want to apply object fusion techniques on this data)

I know it is hard to find the perfect data for it, but I am grateful for any hints where I could find exactly the desired or similiar data. It does not need to be from the automotive field, as long as it covers the topics.

It would be great if I could process the data with Matlab, but I am open to C and C++, too. Though the latter would be the tough road.

Comment: For those who are still interested, here is a link to a source I found myself: http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/index.php